# Redirect user to different site using apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on a specific condition on production environment where I need to redirect user to third part in case a specific url.

I am aware that rewrite rule can be used for this case, however I came across `Redirect` in Apache which can be used if resource moved to another server.

Can any one help me to understand the correct way to do this, I want use for this URL 'www.mysite.com/some/optional parameter/testpage' and `mysite.com/some/optional parameter/testpage` to redirect to `http://testpage.mysite.com/`

```
#With Redirect
Redirect "www.mysite.com/testpage" "http://testpage.mysite.com/"
Redirect "mysite.com/testpage" "http://testpage.mysite.com/"
```

is this correct way to achieve this or I need to take a different approach.

Comment: You can use a 301 (permanent) or 302 (temporary) redirect at the Apache level. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Redirect` directive for matching host name in request. Better to use `mod_rewrite` and do a `301` redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)(thepact)/?$ http://$1.%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: `$1` is basically `testpage` (being captured from `RewriteRule`) and `%1` is part after optional `www` in `RewriteCond` (it will capture `mysite.com` in `%1`). Did you test this rule?

Comment: I tried and it was not working for me, I have some extra parameter after the domain name like `mysite.com/optional/testpage` and for me redirection will happen to different URL and not with in the same URL

Comment: Question says URL is `www.mysite.com/testpage`. Please provide accurate information. What is the full URL you're trying to redirect? Also make sure this rule is very first rule.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it says that I want to redirect `mysite.com/optional/parameters/testpage` to `http://testpage.mysite.com/`, both are hosted on different location. I have updated my question with more clarity

Comment: ok try my updated rule as very first rule in your htaccess after clearing your browser cache completely.

Comment: It seems to be working but the final URL is not correct, final rewrite URL is `mysite.com/US/enhttp://testpage.`  while the one I was expecting is `http://testpage.mysite.com/` which is different one as I want Apache to redirect to this site in case it match my rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113674/discussion-between-anubhava-and-umesh-awasthi).